# Unexpected token error on <?php

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I'm building a webpage that retrieves a series of latitudes and longitudes from a database and then displays these as markers on a google map. It's all working fine, apart from I receive an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < on the opening php tag inside the javascript. Can anyone see why I'm getting this error and offer a way to get past it?

Here's the code in question:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var map;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds ();
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      zoom: 8
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);
  }

//HERE'S WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS  
<?php
  while ($row = $results->fetch_array())
    echo "addMarker(".$row['latitude'].", ".$row['longitude'].", ".$row['time'].", map);";
?>
    function addMarker(lat, lng, time, map) {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map,
            draggable: false,
        });

        bounds.extend(latLng);

        var contentString = 'Time: ' + time + '\n' + 'Latitude: ' + lat + '\n' + 'Longitude: ' + lng;

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });

        return marker;
    }

  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  //]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because of `CDATA` It takes every character literally.

`<?php` will generate an error because the parser interprets **<** as the start of a new `XML` element.

Comment: Okay, so is what I'm attempting impossible? Or is there a way to work around this?

Comment: You cannot mix server and client side save the php data to a html element and read it from there using javascript